# Redirect to customer's store view on login

Tags: magento2, multistore, customer-account, store-view

We would like to redirect to the customer's store view on login, this seems like it should be default behaviour but we always get the default store view (ID: 1). Has anyone accomplished this?

We have an extension which adds 'Login as Customer' functionality to the admin area and bizarrely this *does* redirect the customer to the correct store view, so something is amiss only on the frontend/regular customer login process.

Comment: did you get any solutions on it ??

Comment: @RahulDambare We developed our own extension to solve this I'm afraid, still surprising Magento doesn't offer this as a configuration option.